# Pyspark 3.0 cannot overwrite or drop managed table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I try to overwrite managed table:

```
lego_sets_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('test_table')
```

i get an error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can not create the managed table('`test_table`'). The associated location('file:/C:/Users/gprodanovic/PycharmProjects/pythonPySpark/spark-warehouse/pyspark_workshop.db/test_table') already exists.;
```

this also doesn't work:

```
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;")
```

I'm trying this on Windows 10,  Pyspark 3.0.1, python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Specify the path and see if that helps:

```
lego_sets_df.write.mode("overwrite").option("path", "C:/Users/gprodanovic/PycharmProjects/pythonPySpark/spark-warehouse/pyspark_workshop.db/").saveAsTable('test_table')
```

not sure if `file:/` is necessary, if above doesn't work try it with `file:/C:/Users/gprodanovic/PycharmProjects/pythonPySpark/spark-warehouse/pyspark_workshop.db/`

Comment: It helps, in a way, with path option it's no longer managed table but external (unmanaged) one. But is there a  way to do it with managed table?